# Can't alt + drag in firefox anymore

Tags: javascript, firefox, drag-and-drop

I have some simple drag & drop code that used to work in firefox, chrome, safari. Now it no longer works in FF.

Drag function is:

```
function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
```

Drop function is:

```
function drop(ev, el) {
    {{ irrelevant code }}
    if(ev.altKey){
       {{ code to make copy of node }}
    }
}
```

When I hold alt and drag on Chrome & Safari, it gives me that green plus icon and shows me making a copy of the element I'm dragging. I assume that's built-in browser functionality. I then make the actual copy on drop. This used to work in firefox but not anymore - is this a bug or am I going to have to add code to the drag function to accomodate for this?

Comment: I see a green plus when holding alt whilst dragging, but only when dropping to a textarea. Otherwise the plus does not show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently it works on firefox if you hold click first and THEN hold alt. It wasn't always this way and seems odd to go against the established norm, but figured I'd update this issue.